# Pull current availability from Exchange server

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server

[image]

Is there a mechanism for .Net that would let me pull user availability information like the color coded dots in the picture from Microsoft Lync 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Lync REST APIs](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/what-is-lync-ucwa-api) should meet your needs.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks,

Venkat